# I am getting segmentation fault error after using the ld linker command in linux

Tags: c, linux, linker, segmentation-fault

I have written a simple C program in linux.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a = 0, b = 0, sum = 0;
    a = 6;
    b = 10;
    sum = a + b;

    return 0;
}
```

I have also written the linker script for this:

```
OUTPUT_FORMAT(elf32-i386)
   SECTIONS
{
    . = 0x30000;
    .text : { *(.text) }
    . = 0x8000000;
    .data : { *(.data) }
    .bss : { *(.bss) }
}
```

Now, i have used a linker command:

```
$ ld -o out -T s1.lds sample.o
```

After executing this , i am getting an executable out file.

Now if I try to execute out file using the command,

```
$ ./out
```

in the terminal window,

**I am getting a segmentation fault as an error message**

Comment: The best place to start with your segault will almost always be to compile with debug flags and run it  through GDB

Comment: Improved formatting and added tags.

Comment: Any specific reason you are using a custom linker script? Outside of hardcore OS development, they are usually not necessary.